# Python Pandas to_dict compute time slow and nonlinear

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe and I use to_dict to convert it into a dictionary. Sample code here.

```
data = data_raw.head(1000)
start = time.time()
model = data.set_index('modelid-a')['modelname-a'].to_dict()
end = time.time()
print('Finished model')
print(end - start)
```

For 1000 rows, the compute time is 0.002429 seconds.

For 2000 rows, the compute time is 0.002743 seconds.

For 5000 rows, the compute time is 0.004242 seconds.

For 10,000 rows, the compute time is 0.008217 seconds.

For 20,000 rows, the compute time is 0.571163 seconds.

For 50,000 rows, the compute time is 19.83438 seconds.

For 70,000 rows, the compute time is 47.33981 seconds.

When I go up to 150,000, the compute time is 1789 seconds.

This is painfully slow.

What can I do to optimize this?

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't simply run out of fast RAM, and then hits the swap on a slow hard drive?

Comment: The program only uses 500MB out of 17GB RAM. Disk usage is 0.